# How to extract piece of xml file by python

Tags: python, regex, xml, file, extract

Imagine I have a huge xml file:

```
.
.
.
<div class="span9">
      <div class="results-count">AAA</div>
<div class="AA">
  <div class="A"><a href="/TEST">BBB</a>
  </div>
  <div class="BB"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href="/TEST1" class="B">DDD</a>
    <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src="TEST2" title="C"/><a href="/TEST3" class="D">FFF</a>,
<a href="/TEST4" class="E">GGG</a>
    <div class="clear"></div><a href="/TEST5" class="details">Details</a>
  </div>
  <pre>HHH</pre>
  <div class="clear"></div>
.
.
.
```

I want to say python to show me all lines between `<div class="results-count">AAA</div>` and `<div class="clear"></div>`.

Note: What you see in my sample xml file is repetitive in my huge xml file. so I want to show all these segments as output of my python script.

Comment: I know... But I don't want to use `lxml, xpath` or `xml.etree.ElementTree `

Comment: No/// I don't want to parse... I know `BeautifulSoup` or other methods... needs to do that by regex python

Comment: @MortezaLSC, why are you against using the proper tools for the job?

Comment: @MortezaLSC keep in mind that maybe you could do this job with regex but first of all its hard and also its very very slower than xml parsers like `lxml` .

Comment: @Kasra I have tested I methods... So I want to use regex now :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC so never think about `regex` . because as i say its terrible ! if you want to find the fastest way go and benchmark the xml parsers tools

Comment: I agree with you... But .... I have to... really

Comment: @MortezaLSC i couldn't understand why ? maybe you dont want use something like `Beautifulsoup` that need installation but why not  `xml.etree` ?

Comment: My tags in that websites are really bad to parse and put them inside each other.

Comment: @MortezaLSC what mean by *bad to parse* ? if regex could realysis your string other parsers will could too !

Comment: any way , i suggest to search based on your special problem maybe you found a better answer !

Comment: @MortezaLSC you're welcome dear !

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
<div class="results-count">[^<]+?</div>(.+?)<div class="clear"></div>
```

with flags: `re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL`

[DEMO - one block](https://regex101.com/r/zH3eT0/1)
[DEMO - multiple blocks](https://regex101.com/r/zH3eT0/2)

Please note that the regex stops at the first `<div class="clear"></div>` found.

Here is a sample code in Python:

```
import re

p = re.compile(ur'<div class="results-count">[^<]+?</div>(.+)<div class="clear"></div>', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
test_str = u"<div class=\"span9\">\n      <div class=\"results-count\">AAA</div>\n<div class=\"AA\">\n  <div class=\"A\"><a href=\"/TEST\">BBB</a>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"BB\"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href=\"/TEST1\" class=\"B\">DDD</a>\n    <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src=\"TEST2\" title=\"C\"/><a href=\"/TEST3\" class=\"D\">FFF</a>,\n<a href=\"/TEST4\" class=\"E\">GGG</a>\n    <div class=\"clear\"></div><a href=\"/TEST5\" class=\"details\">Details</a>\n  </div>\n  <pre>HHH</pre>\n  <div class=\"clear\"></div>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: with `re.match`? could you possibly put the python code? Thank you

Comment: You could have at least mentioned the `s` modifier.

Comment: Please check my updates guys: I have added a sample code and the used flags.

Comment: Thank you... but in my script I used: `get_response=session.get(...); content=get_response.content; re.findall(p, content)` . But doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML

Or maybe can HTML Parser.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Start Tag (start_tag):", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "End Tag(end_tag) :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Content :", data

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to parse state between tags

Comment: so go straight to the problem?